# Solving an exponential equation with variable in linear sum

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponential-function, closed-form, exponential-diophantine-equations

I have the following equation:
$$x(1+c-ae^x)=y(1+c-be^y)$$ where $a, b, c$ are constants.

Can I find a closed-form expression of $y$ in terms of $x$ and constants?

Thanks!

Comment: Suggest Lambert's W-function.

Comment: @coffeemath.  I do not think so

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici After a bit of trial I think you're right about Lambert not getting closed form.

Comment: If there should be some close form, then it also covers particular case $K = y(1 + c - b\rm e^y)$ for fixed $K$.   Try examine number of solutions for particular $c$, $b$ with respect to $K$ (see e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x%28-0.02+-+exp%28x%29%29+for+-10+%3C+x+%3C+3).  I really doubt any close form exists.

Comment: @amaths For preventing closing of the question, you should add your background and your trials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is an exponential-polynomial equation.

$$x(c+1-ae^x)=y(c+1-be^y)$$
$$-axe^x+cx+x=-bye^y+cy+y$$
$$-axe^x+cx+x+bye^y=cy+y$$
$$bye^y=cy+y+axe^x-cx-x$$
$$\frac{by}{cy+y+axe^x-cx-x}e^y=1$$
$$\frac{by}{(c+1)y+axe^x-cx-x}e^y=1$$
$$\frac{y}{\frac{(y+1)y+axe^x-cx-x}{c+1}}e^y=\frac{c+1}{b}$$
$$\frac{y}{y+\frac{axe^x-cx-x}{c+1}}e^y=\frac{c+1}{b}$$
$$\frac{y}{y-\frac{-axe^x+cx+x}{c+1}}e^y=\frac{c+1}{b}$$

We see, your equation cannot be solved in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) in the general case. But it can be solved in terms of Generalized Lambert W:

$$y=W\left(^{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0}_{\frac{-axe^x+cx+x}{c+1}};\frac{c+1}{b}\right)=W\left(^{\frac{axe^x-cx-x}{c+1}}_{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0};\frac{b}{c+1}\right)$$

$-$ see the references below.

For $c=-1$, we have the equation $axe^x=bye^y$ with the solutions $y=W\left(\frac{axe^x}{b}\right)\ \ \ (k\in\mathbb{Z})$.

[Mezö 2017] Mezö, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mezö/Baricz 2017] Mezö, I.; Baricz, A.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of *possible* approximation, use (assuming that $1+c \neq b$)
$$f(x)=y \left((1+c)-b e^y\right)=(1+c-b)y-b\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{y^n}{(n-1 )!}$$ and use series reversion to obtain
$$y=t+\frac{b }{1+c-b}t^2+\frac{b  (1+c+3 b)}{2 (1+c-b)^2}t^3+\frac{b \left(16 b^2+13 b (1+c)+(1+c)^2\right)}{6 (1+c-b)^3}t^4+O(t^5)$$ where
$$t=\frac{f(x)}{1+c-b}$$

Comment: Needless to say, this answer is WAYS cooler and useful than mine! $+1$

Comment: Just a note: isn't actually $f(y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing other information, we can only speculate about, but one thing is certain: you cannot get any closed form solution for $y$ in terms of $x$, not even using Lambert $W$ function.

What I do suggest is a sort of "amusement run", where we take the exponential in $y$ and we approximate it with its Taylor series, increasing the order.

**1**

We start with $e^y \sim 1 + y + O(y^2)$.

For the sake of brevity, we will call $T(x) = x(1+c-ae^x)$

Then we have to solve

$$T(x) = y(1 + c - b(1+y))$$

we just get a quadratic equation in $y$, whose solution is

$$y = \frac{-b+c+1}{2 b}\pm\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{b^2-2 b c-4 b T(x)-2 b+c^2+2 c+1}{b^2}}$$

**2**

We increase the order of the Series: $e^y \sim \ + y + \frac{y^2}{2} + O(y^3)$ and we get a cubic painful equation:

$$T(x) = y(1 + c - b(1 + y + y^2/2))$$

whose solutions are

$$y_0 = \frac{\sqrt[3]{20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T+\sqrt{4 \left(2 b^2-6 b k\right)^3+\left(20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T\right)^2}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} b}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(2 b^2-6 b k\right)}{3 b \sqrt[3]{20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T+\sqrt{4 \left(2 b^2-6 b k\right)^3+\left(20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T\right)^2}}}-\frac{2}{3}$$

$$y_1 = -\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T+\sqrt{4 \left(2 b^2-6 b k\right)^3+\left(20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T\right)^2}}}{6 \sqrt[3]{2} b}+\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(2 b^2-6 b k\right)}{3\ 2^{2/3} b \sqrt[3]{20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T+\sqrt{4 \left(2 b^2-6 b k\right)^3+\left(20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T\right)^2}}}-\frac{2}{3}$$

$$y_2 = -\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T+\sqrt{4 \left(2 b^2-6 b k\right)^3+\left(20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T\right)^2}}}{6 \sqrt[3]{2} b}+\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(2 b^2-6 b k\right)}{3\ 2^{2/3} b \sqrt[3]{20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T+\sqrt{4 \left(2 b^2-6 b k\right)^3+\left(20 b^3-36 b^2 k-54 b^2 T\right)^2}}}-\frac{2}{3}$$

Where here $k = 1+c$.

As you see it doesn't get easier. I let you imagine what would be the third order...

Also consider that those solutions are not (or could not be) even approximations of the "real" solutions (assuming to deal with $a, b, c$ fixed numbers) for we are treating the exponential first like a linear function, and secondly like a quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- Just for fun, $x(d-ae^x)=y(d-be^y)\iff \dfrac yx=\dfrac{d-ae^x}{d-be^y}$ so for a real $t$ we have $y=(d-ae^x)t$ and $x=(d-be^y)t$. It follows
$$y=\ln\left(\frac{dt-x}{bt}\right)=(d-ae^x)t$$ Consequently for each value $x_0$ we have a function $$f_{x_0}(t)=\frac{\ln(A-\frac Bt)}{C}$$ where $A,B,C$ are **non-independent** constants.
Graphically we can verify that when this function is well defined it cuts the diagonal just one time and this unique fixed point $t_0$ let us to do $$y_{0}=(d-ae^{x_0})t_0$$

Obviously the task is hard but I have say "just for fun" (and this is just a comment!).